# Как зайти в админку vBulletin?

Tags: форум, vbulletin

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как зайти в административную часть форума vBulletin, если у меня администраторские права?

Comment: Версия 3.8.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
http://site.ru/admincp
```

Если не заходит - посмотри имена каталогов всего форума и прикинь какой из них может быть админкой.

Comment: Или дай ссылку на сайт

Comment: http://i-wko.net/forum/

Answer (score 1):

Я разобрался, вопрос можно закрывать!

Нужно зайти под логином администратора, прокрутить страницу в самый низ и нажать ссылку "Управление" и опять ввести логин и пароль.